# from keras.engine.training import _minimum_control_deps ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use KerasCV in PyCharm and even though I fixed tensor flow with the latest version with another folder. Now I'm having error with the model while it works perfectly with Google Colab. The problem arises when I try to use keras cv and uploading the model on my computer.

I use MacOS M1 and the Operating System version is macOS Ventura 13.4, I use Python 3.10 with PyCharm venv on my project and TensorFlow version is 2.13.0rc1

```
import time
import keras_cv
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = keras_cv.models.StableDiffusion(img_width=512, img_height=512)

images = model.text_to_image("photograph of an astronaut riding a horse", batch_size=3)

def plot_images(images):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    for i in range(len(images)):
        ax = plt.subplot(1, len(images), i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i])
        plt.axis("off")

print(plot_images(images))
```

Comment: having same issue on mac M1 , python 3.11

Comment: Please help us to know about the system OS, Tensorflow and python version you are using? I tried replicating the same code in Mac M1 (python 3.10, TF 2.12) which is not showing any error. @BojanT, Could you please try again using python 3.10? (Attaching the replicated [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/0beb3b4d195dab8b8ef186ca6b508b80/76248288.ipynb) here for your reference).